# Godot Simply decelerating a Vector2

Tags: android, game-physics, godot

Very new to Godot. I'm not thinking about this right as I have had no doing similar in other langs, would appreciate a new set of eyes - thanks!

```
func _physics_process(delta):

if joystick_right and joystick_right.is_pressed:
    rotation = joystick_right.output.angle() + deg_to_rad(90)
    vector = Vector2(cos(rotation-deg_to_rad(90)), sin(rotation-deg_to_rad(90)))
    velocity += vector * acceleration;
    velocity = velocity.limit_length(max_speed)
    print("Velocity: ",velocity)is in
    print("Speed: ", speed)
    print("Acceleration: ",acceleration)
    
move_and_slide()
```

I have tried to detect when joystick is released and to use `int -= 0.01` on speed/acceleration but 'velocity' is moving the object. Trying to reduce 'velocity' in code has been a struggle. For example, I'm looking for something like this in psuedo-code:

```
if (velocity > 0,0):
     velocity -= (0.01,0.01)
     #reduce velocity by 0.01 every sec
```

**This doesn't make sense since velocity includes direction.** I want to maintain direction but slow down to a stop after some time after joystick is released.

I appreciate any advice on why I am going about this so stupidly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are of course aware that you can scale a vector, and that you can use [`limit_length`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-limit-length) (and of course you can get the length of a vector by using [`length`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-length)), so I believe you could find a way to do this if you really wanted to.

---

However you want a simple way to do it.

I believe the simpler way to do it - while being frame rate independent - is using [`move_toward`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-move-toward).

You want your `velocity` to `move_toward` the zero vector, by some "delta" (deceleration):

```
velocity = velocity.move_toward(Vector2.ZERO, deceleration * delta)
```

Here `deceleration * delta` is the maximum change `move_toward` will do. *I'm assuming `deceleration` has acceleration units (velocity per second) and - of course - `delta` has time units (seconds), so by multiplying them we have a delta velocity.*

The `move_toward` will not overshoot. That is, if the distance between `velocity` and `Vector2.ZERO` is greater than `deceleration * delta` you get `Vector2.ZERO` instead of the velocity flipping to the opposite direction.

---

*If you were changing velocity by other means, you could check if the result is going in the opposite direction by checking the [`signf`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@globalscope.html#class-globalscope-method-signf) of the [`dot`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-dot) product. If they are going approximately on the same direction the dot product is positive, if they perpendicular to each other the dot product is zero, and if they are approximately on opposite directions the dot product is negative.*

---

For clarity sake, if you had to implement `move_toward` yourself (you don't), it would be like this:

```
func move_toward(from:Vector2, to:Vector2, step:float) -> Vector2:
    var difference := to - from
    var distance := difference.length()
    if is_zero_approx(distance) or distance < step:
        return to
    else:
        var direction := difference / distance
        return from + direction * step
```

As you can see, here we would be using an `if` to make sure we are not about to overshoot.

Dividing the `difference` by the `distance` gives us a unit vector (assuming the `distance` is not zero, see [`is_zero_approx`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-is-zero-approx)).

Another way to get a unit vector would be using [`normalized`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-normalized). Or we could use [`direction_to`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-direction-to) and [`distance_to`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-distance-to), which might make the code more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough response, I appreciate it. Indeed, I just needed to dig a little and get out of my own way in order to figure this simple issue out, which I did late last night. Thanks to your response, I am much closer to understanding how game physics work and why instead of just trying randomly. :)